# How to execute a specific test from testNg.xml with ant?

Tags: ant, selenium, hudson, testng, build.xml

I have to run different type of tests which are defined in `testNg.xml`.

I am triggering my test from Hudson parameterized build, so based on this parameter(test type) I want to select a particular test in the testNg suite.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please give people credit for their effort to help you and [accept answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/160062) on your previous questions. You haven't accepted a single answer.

Comment: Sure , i am not aware of using "accept" option, sorry for the delay.
Thanks for the info.